# Display a custom taxonomy as a dropdown on the edit posts page

Tags: custom-taxonomy, dropdown

When you create a custom taxonomy, seemingly the only options are to display it as a tag (non-hierarchical) or category (hierarchical). Is there a way to display them as a dropdown menu?

I realise that this an be done using `add_meta_box()` and actually manually adding it, but I'm looking for a builtin way (if one exists), to save lots of code! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way of doing this with `wp_register_taxonomy()`. When you register a taxonomy, the default metabox is either checkboxes (hierarchical) or as a cloud (non-hierarchical).

The only way round it is to de-register the existing metabox and add a new-one in its place. By carefully mimicking the 'default' metabox - you won't have to process the data yourself, but let WordPress automatically handle adding / removing terms.

The details of how to do this are given in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48937/custom-post-type-taxonomies-ui-radiobuttons-not-checkboxes/48942#48942). You may also find this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/stephenh1988/Radio-Buttons-for-Taxonomies) helpful (which now includes the ability of creating terms on the fly in the new metabox). The linked resources refer to creating a metabox with radio boxes, but it could be easily adapted for drop-down menus.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, that is as I feared! Would be great if WP implimented this in the future, would save lots of coding for people like me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 10):

You can add new taxonomy with your own metabox since wp 3.8 by [meta_box_cb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)

"drop_cat()" - consist of rebuild original core category metabox
wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php

```
function realty_type() {
$args = array(
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'meta_box_cb'                => 'drop_cat',
);
register_taxonomy( 'realty_type', array( 'YOUR_POST_TYPE' ), $args );

}

// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'realty_type', 0 );


function drop_cat( $post, $box ) {
$defaults = array('taxonomy' => 'category');
if ( !isset($box['args']) || !is_array($box['args']) )
    $args = array();
else
    $args = $box['args'];
extract( wp_parse_args($args, $defaults), EXTR_SKIP );
$tax = get_taxonomy($taxonomy);
?>
<div id="taxonomy-<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>" class="acf-taxonomy-field categorydiv">

        <?php 
        $name = ( $taxonomy == 'category' ) ? 'post_category' : 'tax_input[' . $taxonomy . ']';
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='{$name}[]' value='0' />"; // Allows for an empty term set to be sent. 0 is an invalid Term ID and will be ignored by empty() checks.
        ?>
        <? $term_obj = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy ); //_log($term_obj[0]->term_id)?>
        <ul id="<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>checklist" data-wp-lists="list:<?php echo $taxonomy?>" class="categorychecklist form-no-clear">
            <?php //wp_terms_checklist($post->ID, array( 'taxonomy' => $taxonomy) ) ?>
        </ul>

        <?php wp_dropdown_categories( array( 'taxonomy' => $taxonomy, 'hide_empty' => 0, 'name' => "{$name}[]", 'selected' => $term_obj[0]->term_id, 'orderby' => 'name', 'hierarchical' => 0, 'show_option_none' => '&mdash;' ) ); ?>

</div>
<?php
}
```

Comment: This worked well for me, but I needed to make a code tweak for WordPress 4.9.5 ... <?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'taxonomy' => $taxonomy, 'hide_empty' => 0, 'name' => "{$name}[]", 'selected' => $term_obj[0]->name, 'orderby' => 'name', 'hierarchical' => 0, 'show_option_none' => '&mdash;','option_none_value'=> '0', 'value_field' => 'name' ); ?>

Comment: This code will work since 3.8 and higher

Comment: did you have to register a custom url for `tax_input` to redirect properly?

Answer (score 7):

Here you go:

```
<select>
    <?php
       $tax_terms = get_terms('your_taxonomy_name', array('hide_empty' => '0'));      
       foreach ( $tax_terms as $tax_term ):  
          echo '<option value="'.$tax_term->name.'">'.$tax_term->name.'</option>';   
       endforeach;
    ?>
</select>
```

Delete $tax_terms second argument if you don't want to display empty terms.

Also use [selected](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/selected) if you want want to save picked option :)

Comment: Thanks @Wordpressor - I'm looking to do it without having to add any metaboxes to the edit post page if I can, so it was built in ways using the `wp_register_taxonomy()` function I was looking for. Will update my question!

Answer (score 1):

I was having difficulty with the code provided by Alexufo, so I rewrote it based on the updated function in WP 4.1.2, Here's my updated drop_cat function:

```
//function below re-purposed from wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php - post_categories_meta_box()
function drop_cat( $post, $box ) {
    $defaults = array( 'taxonomy' => 'category' );
    if ( ! isset( $box['args'] ) || ! is_array( $box['args'] ) ) {
        $args = array();
    } else {
        $args = $box['args'];
    }
    $r = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    $tax_name = esc_attr( $r['taxonomy'] );
    $taxonomy = get_taxonomy( $r['taxonomy'] );
    ?>
    <div id="taxonomy-<?php echo $tax_name; ?>" class="categorydiv">

    <?php //took out tabs for most recent here ?>

        <div id="<?php echo $tax_name; ?>-all">
            <?php
            $name = ( $tax_name == 'category' ) ? 'post_category' : 'tax_input[' . $tax_name . ']';
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='{$name}[]' value='0' />"; // Allows for an empty term set to be sent. 0 is an invalid Term ID and will be ignored by empty() checks.
            ?>
            <ul id="<?php echo $tax_name; ?>checklist" data-wp-lists="list:<?php echo $tax_name; ?>" class="categorychecklist form-no-clear">
                <?php //wp_terms_checklist( $post->ID, array( 'taxonomy' => $tax_name, 'popular_cats' => $popular_ids ) ); ?>
            </ul>

            <?php $term_obj = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, $tax_name ); //_log($term_obj[0]->term_id) ?>
            <?php wp_dropdown_categories( array( 'taxonomy' => $tax_name, 'hide_empty' => 0, 'name' => "{$name}[]", 'selected' => $term_obj[0]->term_id, 'orderby' => 'name', 'hierarchical' => 0, 'show_option_none' => "Select $tax_name" ) ); ?>

        </div>
    <?php if ( current_user_can( $taxonomy->cap->edit_terms ) ) : 
            // removed code to add terms here dynamically, because doing so added a checkbox above the newly added drop menu, the drop menu would need to be re-rendered dynamically to display the newly added term ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <p><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=<?php echo $tax_name ?>&post_type=YOUR_POST_TYPE">Add New</a></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

The one issue I'm having (as indicated by my comments in the above function), is that I cannot use the WP core add term/category feature in the meta box, because it defaults to dynamically adding new terms as a checkbox above my select menu. In order to work with a select menu, the menu will need to be re-rendered after the new term is added. Something I'm sure I could figure out but will leave for another day.

Answer (score 0):

the above code have some issues on me, let me put the right code that worked for me

```
 'meta_box_cb' => 'drop_cat',
```

your category definition , then put this code in here

remember to put

```
function drop_cat( $post, $box ) {
    if ( ! isset( $box['args'] ) || ! is_array( $box['args'] ) ) {
        $args = array();
    } else {
        $args = $box['args'];
    }
    $r = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    $tax_name = esc_attr( $r['taxonomy'] );
    $taxonomy = get_taxonomy( $r['taxonomy'] );
    ?>
    <div id="taxonomy-<?php echo $tax_name; ?>" class="categorydiv">

    <?php //took out tabs for most recent here ?>

        <div id="<?php echo $tax_name; ?>-all">
            <?php
            $name = ( $tax_name == 'category' ) ? 'post_category' : 'tax_input[' . $tax_name . ']';
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='{$name}[]' value='0' />"; // Allows for an empty term set to be sent. 0 is an invalid Term ID and will be ignored by empty() checks.
            ?>
            <ul id="<?php echo $tax_name; ?>checklist" data-wp-lists="list:<?php echo $tax_name; ?>" class="categorychecklist form-no-clear">
                <?php //wp_terms_checklist( $post->ID, array( 'taxonomy' => $tax_name, 'popular_cats' => $popular_ids ) ); ?>
            </ul>

            <?php $term_obj = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, $tax_name ); //_log($term_obj[0]->term_id) 
          
            ?>
            <?php wp_dropdown_categories( array( 'taxonomy' => $tax_name, 'option_none_value' => 0 ,'id'=>$term_obj[0]->term_id, 'value_field'=> 'slug' , 'hide_empty' => 0, 'name' => "{$name}[]", 'selected' => $term_obj[0]->slug, 'orderby' => 'name', 'hierarchical' => 0, 'show_option_none' => "Select $tax_name" ) ); ?>

        </div>
    <?php if ( current_user_can( $taxonomy->cap->edit_terms ) ) : 
            // removed code to add terms here dynamically, because doing so added a checkbox above the newly added drop menu, the drop menu would need to be re-rendered dynamically to display the newly added term ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <p><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=<?php echo $tax_name ?>&post_type=YOUR_POST_TYPE">Add New</a></p>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
```